# SSRS Format calculated timespan in dd:hh:mm:ss

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

I have a report and one of the fields calculates a timespan in an expression e.g

```
=Fields!Date1.Value-Fields!Date2.Value
```

I would like to display in the format dd:hh:mm:ss so days,hours,minutes and seconds. If i just leave the expression it sort of works but i get milliseconds which i don't want and if there are no days then that value disappears.

I've seen lots of examples using formatting to get HH:mm:ss but not on how to do the days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @alejandro's answer I ended up with

```
=Format(Floor(DateDiff("s",Fields!Date1.Value,Fields!Date2.Value)/86400),"00") 
& ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", (Fields!Date2.Value-Fields!Date1.Value).TotalSeconds, 
"00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

just doing the straight subtraction didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=Floor(DateDiff("s",Fields!Date1.Value,Fields!Date2.Value) / 86400) & ":" & 
Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!Date1.Value-Fields!Date2.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

It will give you `dd:HH:mm:ss` format. Note `Date1` must be greater than `Date2`.

Comment: hmmm i'm getting an error stating that '/' is not defined for type 'Date' and type 'Integer'