# DateDiff with DateTime in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to calculate the time difference between two DateTime parameters in a SSRS expression to display in `DD:hh:mm:ss` format. With the expression I am using I am getting:

```
 Start: 03/04/2016 08:48:53 AM    End: 03/07/2016 11:24:04 AM    Elapsed: 74:33:11.
```

I would like to see `Elapsed: 3:02:35:11`  (days:hours:minutes:seconds).

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461898/ssrs-format-calculated-timespan-in-ddhhmmss/35466381#35466381)

Comment: This is the expression I am currently using: =RIGHT("00" & Floor(SUM(DateDiff("s",Fields!ProcessOpened.Value,Fields!ProcessClosed.Value))/3600),2) 
& ":" & RIGHT("00" & (Floor(SUM(DateDiff("s",Fields!ProcessOpened.Value,Fields!ProcessClosed.Value)) Mod 3600)/60),2) 
& ":" & RIGHT("00" & SUM(DateDiff("s",Fields!ProcessOpened.Value,Fields!ProcessClosed.Value)) Mod 60,2)

Answer (score 0):

Divide the hours by 24 to get Days, and then do a Modulo to get the remaining hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=Floor(
DateDiff("s",Fields!ProcessOpened.Value,Fields!ProcessClosed.Value)
/ 86400) & ":" & Format(DateAdd("s",
DateDiff("s",Fields!ProcessOpened.Value,
Fields!ProcessClosed.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

I've tested with:

```
=Floor(DateDiff("s",CDATE("04/03/2016 08:48:53 AM"),
CDATE("07/03/2016 11:24:04 AM")) / 86400) & ":" &
Format(DateAdd("s", DateDiff("s",CDATE("04/03/2016 08:48:53 AM"),
CDATE("07/03/2016 11:24:04 AM")), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

It returns:

```
3:02:35:11
```

Let me know if this helps.